# Shoud the classes have always have a connectivity in UML?

Tags: java, class, uml, class-diagram

Should the classes always have connectivity in UML? For example, in the following diagram, class `Zugriff` is not connected to any other classes. It that a valid or correct class diagram in UML?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You **SHOULD** but not *MUST*.

> Class diagram is UML structure diagram which shows the structure of the designed system at the level of classes and interfaces, shows their features, constraints, and relationships - associations, generalizations, dependencies, etc.
> (from https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html)

These classes and interfaces should have a type of relationship so that it makes sense to put them together. A typical relationship is a generic (weak) `use`.

Comment: So,mine is not wrong,or shoud I make a use realtionship to all classes that connects Zugriff with every class in UML.Please answer!

Comment: Yours is not wrong. You have decided that based on whether your audience needs to know about that relationship. Think about who is reading the diagram.

Comment: This is reading my professor,which do you think is better?

Comment: I would add it **if** those classes really "use" it.

Comment: Do you mean like that,what I posted now?.They use it,so I would make a weak relationship(use)

Comment: Yes. I would like to see it if I was your professor :)